# Windows Live Photo Gallery and CakePHP

Tags: windows, cakephp, gallery, live, photo

I am currently working on a CakePHP application that includes among other things a photo album that will be mainly maintained by an administrator.

I have now started to develop the Photo Album section of the site and was wondering about he following:

- I know I have still to research into Windows Live Photo Gallery API
- I am planning on using CakePHP Media Plugin to process my uploads and place each pictures in its corresponding folder.

However, what is the best approach to tackle this?

Should I create a Model/Controller with functions to handles this. For examples `wluploads.php` for the model and `wluploads_controller.php`. The model would then actsAs the Media Plugin.

Within the controller I would have actions like `function upload(){`, etc, to handle automatically/looped file uploads.

Is this a good approach. Can someone shed some light into some better approach?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find it easier (if you're comfortable with cakephp) just to create your own models/controllers and write the corresponding actions than using a plugin.

> Should I create a Model/Controller with functions to handles this. For examples wluploads.php for the model and wluploads_controller.php. The model would then actsAs the 
>   Media Plugin.
>
> Within the controller I would have actions like function upload(){, etc, to handle automatically/looped file uploads.
>
> Is this a good approach. Can someone shed some light into some better approach?

That is pretty much how I would do it - make a mode/controller with the relevant actions (upload_image etc) and post to the WL Photo Gallery API.

Comment: Concerning WL Photo Gallery API, I would write a C# publishing plugin to use in PC so Photo Gallery can use to upload files to my site. No WL Photo Gallery API or files will reside in my server. I will just need specific code on the site to handle WL Photo Gallery Publishing Plugin calls and uploads to the server. When I am ready I will attempt to work on it. If I am successful starting it, I will post it somewhere so others can contribute. I think CakePHP will benefit if something like that is available.